# remove all rows including words (character) in numpy 2d array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I remore words in my 2d array:
from:

```
array([['111', 'ACTG1'],
       ['131', '124'],
       ['95', '123'],
       ['95', '124'],
       ['95', 'ACTG1'],
       ['ACTG1', '111'],
       ['ACTG1', '95'],
       ['138', '171']]
```

to:

```
array(['131', '124'],
       ['95', '123'],
       ['95', '124'],
       ['138', '171']]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd treat it as a list of lists, or even a flat list, and apply a string method or `re` to create new strings - doing this in a list comprehension.  There isn't anything special in `numpy` to do this.

Comment: is this okay to do this with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
arr = arr[np.char.isnumeric(arr).sum(axis=1) == 2]
print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
[['131' '124']
 ['95' '123']
 ['95' '124']
 ['138' '171']]
```

---

Or:

```py
arr = arr[np.char.isnumeric(arr).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension:

```
a = [['111', 'ACTG1'],
       ['131', '124'],
       ['95', '123'],
       ['95', '124'],
       ['95', 'ACTG1'],
       ['ACTG1', '111'],
       ['ACTG1', '95'],
       ['138', '171']]
```

```
[i for i in a if all([j.isnumeric() for j in i[0]+i[1]])]
```

Output:

```
[['131', '124'],
  ['95', '123'],
  ['95', '124'],
  ['138', '171']]
```